# I need to split a table by range in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

| ID | names | address | post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22xxx | xxx | hhh | oooo |
| .... | ... | .... | .... |

The table has over 5000 entries. I need to split this table in RStudio using the ID column. The ID column is an integer vector with 5 digits. I need to group them by first digit and create a table for each group i.e from 10000-19999 table 1, from 20000-29999 table 2, and so on.

Any help will be appreciated. Am a newbie in R.

Comment: Could you please provide your dataset, or a mock dataset, either here, or on pastebin (please copy and provide the link here)

Also, could you provide a sample of what you actually want done? it's helps us understand what you would like done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R simple subsetting:

```
table1 <- data[which(data$id > 10000 & data$id < 19999), ]
table2 <- data which(data$id > 20000 & data$id < 29999), ]
```

Base R with `subset` function:

```
table1 <- subset(data, id > 10000 & id < 19999)
table2 <- subset(data, id > 20000 & id < 29999)
```

Using `dplyr` in the tidyverse way:

```
library(dplyr)

table1 <- 
  data %>%
  dplyr::filter(id > 10000, id < 19999)

table2 <- 
  data %>%
  dplyr::filter(id > 20000, id < 29999)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to split data into list of dataframes where each dataframe would be 10k ID's.

```
result <- split(df, ceiling(df$ID/10000))
```

`result[[1]]` would have ID's 1-10000, `result[[2]]` would have 10001-20000 and so on.